# Provide login information to connection string?

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-config, app-config

Trying to build connection string to connect to SQL Server that runs on the same PC. I use Windows Authentication mode in order to connect by using SQL Server Management Studio.

Database name: `[dbo].[LearnCSharp]`

`App.config` connection strings section element:

```
<add name="LearnCSharpConn" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=LearnCSharp;"/>
```

I get this exception during connection:

> Cannot open database "LearnCSharp" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'GM\Iam'.

What is wrong with my connection string? Should I provide password there?

Answer (score 1):

Your connection string looks like a LocalDB connection string, but you are saying to be connecting to a SQL Server instance.

In order to use SQL Server, you need a connection string like this:

```
Server=.;Database=LearnCSharp;Integrated Security=True;
```

The `.` in the `Server` denotes 'current machine, default instance', which I presume you are using. The `Integrated Security=True;` indicates to use Windows authentication.

If you are using LocalDB, it should look like this:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\YourDatabaseFile.mdf;Integrated Security=True
```

Replace `YourDatabaseFile.mdf` by your actual database file name.

Comment: Got exception : Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\LearnCSharp.mdf;Integrated Security=True
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Unable to open the physical file "D:\C#nonsens\learncsharp\Data access\LearnCSharp.mdf". Operating system error 5: "5(Access is denied.)".

Comment: Does that file exist?

Comment: Yes, file "D:\C#nonsens\learncsharp\Data access\LearnCSharp.mdf" exists

Comment: From where are you opening it? Web app or desktop app?

Comment: I open it from desktop console app